# How to check if logged in user have pending custom post?

Tags: wp-query, functions

I want to show a message to users who have their post pending for approval. I can do it with wp query like below but wondering if there is more efficient way, like a function; something looks like this `user_has_post( $post_type, $post_status, $user_id)` (returns true or false) that is more efficient that wp query.

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    //check if user has already written a review.
    $review_args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'review',
        'post_status'   => 'pending',
        'author'        => get_current_user_id(),
        ),
    );
    $review_query = new WP_Query($review_args);
    if ($review_query->have_posts()){
        echo 'You already have review pending for approval';
    }
}
```

Comment: No, for this type of thing a WP_Query like you're doing makes the most sense. You can output it to a dashboard widget or admin notice rather than echoing.

Comment: I won't be echoing anything. It was just an example. I will show/not show review form to users based on if they have reviewed before or not.